# How can I do a ussd call in xamarin platform?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, call, ussd

I wish to write a program in xamarin cross platform that will make ussd (#121#) call with one click in xamarin app. I am very new in xamarin... your help is of great need.thanks in advance.

Comment: there are lots of existing questions regarding USSD in iOS.  Have you read them?  Your question as written is pretty broad

Comment: Yes I read but it doesn't call, it only populate the dialler with number without initiating the call  That is ,the call will be manual and when it contains # like (#121#) it only open the dialler without #121#.  Please I need cross platform xamarin c# in vs.

Comment: you can't initiate a phone call on iOS without user interaction

Comment: Please help me to do it with Android using cross platform platform xamarin.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try it and get back to you

Comment: @jason, am very grateful, it seems the solution is done on Android but not Android cross platform

Comment: there is likely not a pre-written cross platform solution for this.  You will need to do it yourself and use DependencyService or some other mechanism to expose it to Forms